# AIR android serversocket works only in ADL (air debug launcher)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

My problem is that I am working on an air app that communicates with each other through serversocket (server) socket (client)

When I test it in Air debug launcher everything works on the server side (I can see the server from a different internet connection)

But when I try to host from Android device it only works on LAN (can't see hosted server from the different connection)

My question is why it works in the Test environment but not in the built APP.. soo frustrating.

here is my serverside code:

```
package AS {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import AS.Constants;
import flash.net.ServerSocket;
import flash.net.Socket;
import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

public class chatPage extends MovieClip {


    private var server:ServerSocket;
    private var clients:Vector.<Socket> = new Vector.<Socket>;
    private var clientUsernames:Array = new Array();
    private var autoScroll:Boolean=true;
    private var autoClean:Boolean=false;
    private var counter:int=900;
    private var soundwarn:Boolean=true;
    private var myformat:TextFormat=new TextFormat();



    public function chatPage(address:String="0.0.0.0",port:uint=8888):void {



        server = new ServerSocket();
        server.bind(port,address);
        server.addEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, serverConnectHandler);
        server.listen();

        if(!server.listening){
            die();
            Constants.mainRef.initLoginScreen("not listening");
        }else if(!server.bound){
            die();
            Constants.mainRef.initLoginScreen("not bound");
        }

        myformat.color=0xffffff;
        client_list.setRendererStyle("textFormat",myformat);

        soundButton.gotoAndStop(1);

        chat_txt.text = String("");
        chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
        scrollBar.update();


        scrollBar.addEventListener(Event.SCROLL, scrollingListener);
        send_txt.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, commandHandler);
        autoClean_btn.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, autoCleanHandler);


        soundButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, soundClickHandler);
        close_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeHandler);

        kick_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kickHandler);
        ban_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, banHandler);
        burn_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, burnHandler);
        share_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareHandler);
        scroll_down_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scrollDownHandler);

        preventSleep_check.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, sleepChangeHandler);

    }
    private function burnHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        //burn all evidence for you and all your clients
        if(chat_txt.length > 0){
            send(4,Constants.mainRef.encrypt("burn"));

            chat_txt.text = String("");
            chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
            scrollBar.update();
        }
    }
    private function shareHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        //share the contents of your chat_txt to all your clients
        if(chat_txt.length > 0){
            send(5,Constants.mainRef.encrypt(chat_txt.text));
        }
    }
    private function banHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var tempIpArr:Array = new Array();
        for (var i: uint = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
            tempIpArr.push(clients[i].remoteAddress);
        }
        Constants.STAGE.addChild(new listDialog(clientUsernames, tempIpArr, this) ); 
    }
    private function sleepChangeHandler(e:Event):void{
        if(this.preventSleep_check.selected){
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
        }else{
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
        }
    }
    private function kickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if(client_list.selectedIndex > -1){
            clients[client_list.selectedIndex].close();
            clients[client_list.selectedIndex].removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
            clients[client_list.selectedIndex].removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, socketDisconnectHandler);
            clients.splice(client_list.selectedIndex,1);
            //send("▼"+clientUsernames[client_list.selectedIndex]);
            send(3,String(clientUsernames[client_list.selectedIndex]));
            clientUsernames.splice(client_list.selectedIndex,1);
            client_list.dataProvider = new DataProvider( clientUsernames );
        }   
    }
    public function remoteKick(index:uint):void{
        clients[index].close();
        clients[index].removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
        clients[index].removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, socketDisconnectHandler);
        clients.splice(index,1);
        send(3,String(clientUsernames[index]));
        clientUsernames.splice(index,1);
        client_list.dataProvider = new DataProvider( clientUsernames );
    }
    private function scrollDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        autoScroll=true;
        chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
        scrollBar.update();
    }
    private function closeHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        die();
        Constants.mainRef.initLoginScreen("Chat room terminated!");
        //Constants.STAGE.addChild(new logInScreen("Chat room terminated!"));
    }
    private function soundClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if(soundButton.currentFrame == 1){
            soundwarn=false;
            soundButton.gotoAndStop(2);
        }else{
            soundwarn=true;
            soundButton.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
    }

    private function autoCleanFrameListener(e:Event):void {
        if(autoClean){
            counter--;
            counter_txt.text = String( Math.floor( counter / 30 ) + "s" );
            if(counter <= 0){
                counter_txt.text = String("30s");
                chat_txt.text = String("");
                chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
                scrollBar.update();
                currentDataStr = String("");
                counter=900;
            }
        }
    }

    private function autoCleanHandler(e:Event):void {

            if(autoClean_btn.selected){
                autoClean=true;
                counter_txt.text = String("30s");
                this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, autoCleanFrameListener);
            }else{
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, autoCleanFrameListener);
                autoClean=false;
                counter_txt.text = String("");
                counter=900;
            }

    }
    private function scrollingListener(e:Event):void {
        if(chat_txt.scrollV!=chat_txt.maxScrollV){
            autoScroll=false;
        }
    }
    private function serverConnectHandler(e:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void {
        var socket:Socket = e.socket;
        var banned:Boolean;
        if(Constants.banList.length > 0){
            for (var i: uint = 0; i < Constants.banList.length; i++) {
                if(Constants.banList[i] == socket.remoteAddress){
                    banned=true;
                    break;
                }else{
                    banned=false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            banned=false;
        }

        if(!banned){

            clients.push(socket);
            clients[clients.length-1].addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
            clients[clients.length-1].addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, socketDisconnectHandler);
            send(2,Constants.mainRef.encrypt(Constants.mainRef.username));

        }else{
            socket.close();
        }
    }


    private function socketDisconnectHandler(e:Event):void {
        send(3,Constants.mainRef.encrypt( clientUsernames[clients.indexOf(e.target)] ) );
        clientUsernames.splice(clients.indexOf(e.target),1);
        client_list.dataProvider = new DataProvider( clientUsernames );
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(e.target),1);
        e.target.close();
        e.target.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, socketDisconnectHandler);
    }

    private var currentDataStr:String;
    private var currentDataType:uint;
    private function socketDataHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
        var socket:Socket = e.currentTarget as Socket;
        currentDataType = socket.readUnsignedInt();
        currentDataStr = socket.readUTFBytes(socket.bytesAvailable);


        send(currentDataType, currentDataStr);
        if(currentDataType == 1){
            chat_txt.appendText(Constants.mainRef.decrypt(currentDataStr) );
            if(autoScroll){
                chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
            }
            scrollBar.update();
            if(soundwarn){
                //give sound warning
                var snd:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("sound/ding.mp3")); 
                snd.play();
            }
        }else if(currentDataType == 2){
            var tempString:String = Constants.mainRef.decrypt(currentDataStr);
            clientUsernames.push(tempString);
            client_list.dataProvider = new DataProvider( clientUsernames );
        }

        tempString=String("");
        currentDataStr=String("");
        currentDataType=0;
    }



    private function commandHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(e.keyCode==13){
        //ENTER GOT PRESSED
            var commandStr:String = send_txt.text;
            if(commandStr.indexOf(".") == 0){
                if(commandStr.indexOf(".del") > -1 ){
                    chat_txt.text = String("");
                    currentDataStr = String("");
                    chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
                    scrollBar.update();
                }else if(commandStr.indexOf(".burn") > -1 ){
                    if(chat_txt.length > 0){
                        send(4,Constants.mainRef.encrypt("burn"));
                        chat_txt.text = String("");
                        chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
                        scrollBar.update();
                    }
                }else if(commandStr.indexOf(".share") > -1 ){
                    if(chat_txt.length > 0){
                        send(5,Constants.mainRef.encrypt(chat_txt.text));
                    }
                }else if(commandStr.indexOf(".ip") > -1 ){
                    getIpOnline();
                }else if(commandStr.indexOf(".roll") > -1 ){
                    var rngMax:int = parseInt( commandStr.slice(commandStr.indexOf(" ")) );
                    if(rngMax > 0){
                        var rawString:String = Constants.mainRef.username + " rolled " + String(Constants.mainRef.randomNum(1,rngMax)) + " out of " + String(rngMax) + "\n";
                        send(1, Constants.mainRef.encrypt( rawString ) );
                        chat_txt.appendText( rawString );
                        if(autoScroll){
                            chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
                        }
                        scrollBar.update();
                    }

                }else if(commandStr.indexOf(".kick") > -1 && client_list.selectedIndex > -1){
                    clients[client_list.selectedIndex].close();
                    clients[client_list.selectedIndex].removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
                    clients[client_list.selectedIndex].removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, socketDisconnectHandler);
                    clients.splice(client_list.selectedIndex,1);

                    send(3,Constants.mainRef.encrypt( clientUsernames[client_list.selectedIndex] ) );

                    clientUsernames.splice(client_list.selectedIndex,1);
                    client_list.dataProvider = new DataProvider( clientUsernames );
                }
            }else if(commandStr.length > 0){
                send(1, Constants.mainRef.encrypt(Constants.mainRef.username + ": " + commandStr + "\n"));
                chat_txt.appendText(Constants.mainRef.username + ": " + commandStr + "\n");
                if(autoScroll){
                    chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
                }
                scrollBar.update();
            }
            send_txt.text = String("");
            commandStr = String("");
            Constants.STAGE.focus = null;
        }
    }

    public function send(typeIndex:uint, data:String):void {
        for each(var client:Socket in clients){
            client.writeUnsignedInt(typeIndex);
            client.writeUTFBytes(data);
            client.flush();
        }
    }

    private function getIpOnline():void{
        var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://api.ipify.org/");
        phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
        var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
        phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
    }
    private function showResult(e:Event):void{
        send_txt.text = String(e.target.data);
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
    }

    public function die():void{
        var i:uint

        for(i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
            clients[i].close();
            clients[i].removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
            clients[i].removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, socketDisconnectHandler);
        }
        server.removeEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, serverConnectHandler);
        server.close();

        chat_txt.text = String("");
        send_txt.text = String("");
        kick_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kickHandler);
        ban_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, banHandler);
        preventSleep_check.removeEventListener(Event.CHANGE, sleepChangeHandler);
        close_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeHandler);
        burn_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, burnHandler);
        share_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareHandler);
        scroll_down_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scrollDownHandler);
        soundButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, soundClickHandler);
        autoClean_btn.removeEventListener(Event.CHANGE, autoCleanHandler);
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, autoCleanFrameListener);
        scrollBar.removeEventListener(Event.SCROLL, scrollingListener);
        send_txt.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, commandHandler);


        clients.length=0;
        clientUsernames.length=0;
        if(Constants.cardIndexer.length > 0){
            for (i = 0; i < Constants.cardIndexer.length; i++) {
                Constants.cardIndexer[i].die(4);
            }
            Constants.cardIndexer.length=0;
            Constants.deckRef.length=0;
        }
        this.parent.removeChild(this);

    }

    private function chatText(texty:String,chat:Boolean=true):void{
        if(chat){
            send(1, Constants.mainRef.encrypt(Constants.mainRef.username + ": " + texty + "\n"));
            chat_txt.appendText(Constants.mainRef.username + ": " + texty + "\n");
            if(autoScroll){
                chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
            }
            scrollBar.update();
        }else{
            send(1, Constants.mainRef.encrypt(texty + "\n"));
            chat_txt.appendText(texty + "\n");
            if(autoScroll){
                chat_txt.scrollV=chat_txt.maxScrollV;
            }
            scrollBar.update();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Ah yes (before sb try to ask) i tested with all the permissions so i bet its not about permissions.

Comment: AIR or not, server socket must be bound to an IP address. If it is bound to localhost (or 127.0.0.1), then the socket is visible from current device only. If it is bound to LAN (192.168.xxx.yyy something), then the socket is visible for LAN devices. The global visibility (to the whole Internet) is available only if you bind your server socket to external IP address.

Comment: when i try to bind serversocket to my so called external IP address this happens: Error: Error #2002: Operation attempted on invalid socket.
But.. its not the problem since i can bind my server to 0.0.0.0 in ADL and still able to see it from client (from different internet) the problem is that if i try to host from other than ADL it not works.. So maybe ADL got some special privilage or something idk..

Comment: It's time for you to provide some code. Also, don't forget to explain the way you obtain your device's external IP address.

Comment: Please stay true to **MCVE** principles: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It's good you are sharing the code, but I believe most of it is irrelevant to the problem. BTW, how do you figure the external IP to connect to when you try the "over internet" setup?

Comment: https://api.ipify.org/ this site returns it in plain text format pure rdy to use. shame i cant bind server on it cuz it produce runtime error.

Comment: OK i still struggling with the problem but i found an interesting fact about adobe air. If i port forward in my router and than click Test with air 26.0 SDK active, it works like a charm in ADL i can see myself being OPEN here: https://portchecker.co/check BUT.. anything other than that not works (show CLOSE) i build app than install not works.. only time it works as it should is when i launch it with ADL.. omg this driving me crazy.. I bet it has something to do with some hidden security future that i have no clue how to terminate.

Comment: I got an idea. Mobile apps has quite a lot of permissions. Build a test desktop AIR app and run it. If desktop server socket will be open and available, that will narrow your problem to Android manifest permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will struggle with this problem in the future.
Mainly 2 things required to be able to host a socket server successfully visible from 
the internet:

-port forwarding.

-put your air app in firewall "allow" list.
(in my situation this was the missing part. ouch!)

Now everything works as it should.